# How to set actionBar popup background?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, popup, toolbar

i am trying to change popup background in `android.support.v7.widget.toolbar`

was trying thisone but it doesnot help:

```
<style name="DonorUaTheme.ActionBar.Solid" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/material_drawer_primary</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle|showHome</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/material_drawer_primary</item>
    </style>
```

i am using android v15, so i can not just set `<item name="android:popupTheme">`, but i still need to change popup background.

will be glad any help

Comment: What is exactly want .. You change actionBar color ya create custom actionBar .. what you want..

Comment: There wont be 'android:' prefix when using app compat theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the background color of the popup menu as below.

1. Create a style in your styles.xml for popup menu.

   ```
   <style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/YourColor</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Set this theme as your toolbar popup theme in your toolbar.xml

   ```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

               // Your code here
           app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
           app:popupTheme="@style/PopupMenuStyle" />
   ```

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in styles.xml file

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

</style>
```

Comment: What IED are use Eclipse ya Android Studio

Comment: i am using android studio

Comment: Than it work properly ... this code is change action bar background color . I am also use this code and this is work properly.

Comment: Please read the question and it's requirement properly. @Destro

Comment: @Pooja, maybe you have some idea how to fix my problem?